# How to conditionally define a field type in a Zod schema based on another field's value?

Tags: javascript, validation, zod

```js
const carSchema = z.object({
  condition: z.enum(['new', 'used']),
  ...someOtherSharedFields,
  conditionalField: z.union([z.object({foo: z.string()}), z.object({bar: z.number()})])
})
```

How I can implement such kind of schema so that if the 'condition' is 'new', the 'conditionalField' is of type { foo: string }, and if the 'condition' is 'used', the 'conditionalField' will be of type { bar: number }?

The solution to which I've come up using discriminated unions:

```js
const someSharedSchema = ...;

const carNewSchema = someSharedSchema.extend({
  condition: z.literal('new'),
  conditionalField: z.object({foo: z.string()})
})

const carUsedSchema = someSharedSchema.extend({
  condition: z.literal('used'),
  conditionalField: z.object({bar: z.number()})
})

const carSchema = z.discriminatedUnion('condition', [carNewSchema, carUsedSchema])
```

Maybe there other possible solutions that might be easier to implement, especially when dealing with many (tens or more) conditions and various types of conditional fields.